# Is it possible to remove a method from a module?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Can I remove a method from a ready module in python? Recently i was trying to write a python code in a browser based trading platform where in they allow usto import python 'time' package but the time package didn't have sleep() method. While i was trying to import sleep method it gave me attribute error. On asking the technical support people of that platform i got to know that they don't support sleep() method. I am just wondering how could we do that? is it just deleting the method from the package? Or are there any better ways?

Comment: Edit the source code.

Comment: Most likely they just exposed their own `time` module somewhere on the import path, so it's picked before built-ins

Comment: @j0hn but there were other methods available like time.now() and all. So you think they just created their own time package with al the methods in it except sleep() is it?

Comment: Since it's an online platform, they have to run things on it before it gets executed. It looks like a security measure.

Comment: It might also be `datetime.time` package, which is based on `datetime` module and there is no time specific methods like `sleep`. If you have permission to make your own imports, then you may try `import time as t_time` or such. Or try to call `datetime.time` methods to be sure it is from `datetime` module. If it is, then you can try to achieve what you want from `datetime.time`

Comment: @fallenAngel i checked and i am pretty usre that it is not datetime.time

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible to remove methods (functions) from a name space at run time.
This is called monkey patching.  Example in an interactive session:

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import time
>>> time.sleep(2)
>>> del time.sleep
>>> time.sleep(2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'sleep'
```

But back to your original question: I believe that on the platform you are using they might have replaced several standard library modules (including the time module) with customized versions. So you should ask them how you can achieve the delay you want without having to resort to busy waiting.

Answer (score 1):

```
import time
time.sleep(1)

del time.sleep
time.sleep(1)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-07a34f5b1e42> in <module>()
----> 1 time.sleep(1)

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'sleep'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have the `time.sleep` method, you can easily write your own (albeit not likely as precise or efficient):

```
def sleep(seconds):
    a = time.time()
    b = time.time()
    while b - a < seconds:
        b = time.time()
```

Here are some tests for precision that I ran (only a print statement to see how often it went into the loop):

```
>>> sleep(1)
2.86102294922e-06
0.0944359302521
0.14835691452
0.198939800262
0.249089956284
0.299441814423
0.349442958832
0.398970842361
0.449244022369
0.498914003372
0.549893856049
0.600338935852
0.648976802826
0.700131893158
0.750012874603
0.800500869751
0.850263834
0.900727987289
0.950336933136
1.00087189674
```

The precision stays at 100th mile seconds precision. :)
You might not have the method either because they modified the source code, or ran some things on the interpreter before your code began executed (using the `del` keyword like in the other answers).

Comment: That is the so called busy waiting I mentioned in my reply above. This would burn cpu cycles.

Comment: It's a quick fix, because since it's an online platform, they may have removed it for security issues. But I agree, it's not the best of options.

Comment: I know how to implement the delay without sleep. i just want to know how they could have removed sleep()